# pptp port 1723 unreachable

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp, ufw

I'm trying to setup a pptp VPN on my server, but for some reasons the server is not responding to me.

on the server I have:

```
$ sudo netstat -alpn | grep :1723
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9636/pptpd
```

I'm using UFW as firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1723                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
1723 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

also :

```
$ grep -v "#" /etc/pptpd.conf
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
logwtmp
localip 10.0.0.1
remoteip 10.0.0.10-100

$ grep -v "#" /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 208.67.222.222
ms-dns 208.67.220.220
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

and :

```
$ sudo grep -v "#" /etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]

-A ufw-before-input -p 47 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p 47 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --sport 1723 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -p tcp -d 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type source-quench -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

My mac os cannot connect to the server, and when I do `$ telnet my-ip 1723` I get no connection, while `$ telnet my-ip 443` or other ports I get a connection,

what could it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using macOS Sierra?

macOS Sierra has removed PPTP Support altogether, see here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206844